# Edit properties of python matplotlib vlines (LineCollection) interactively from navigation toolbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, properties, uinavigationbar

I'd like to change the properties (color, alpha, linewidth) of matplotlib `vlines` or `LineCollection` objects interactively via the navigation toolbar, all line segments have the same properties. While this works great for ordinary plots (see second figure), I can only change the general axes properties (scale, label etc.) for `vlines` but there is no "Curves" tab.

I've attached a MWE but this is actually used in a larger project inside a Qt widget where `vlines` are used as a faster replacement for stem plots. Some additional "glue logic" wouldn't be a problem but I have no idea where to start.

This behaviour is the same for matplotlib 2.x and 3.x.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.vlines(x, x, 0, label="vlines")
ax.plot(x, x, c="red", label="plot")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you might be interested in the fact that `stem` now has a `use_line_collection` argument, which can be set to True to get a faster `LineCollection` instead of individual lines.

Comment: The figure options dialog is at [matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/qt_editor/figureoptions.py). You may monkey patch the `figure_edit` function to change it to your needs.

Comment: It's good to know that the performance of stem plots has been improved - I'll give it a try!

Comment: For the time being, I'll try messing around with the `figure_edit` function to support users with older matplotlib versions as well. Also off-topic: Do you know why the much slower Line2D version has been chosen?